# uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Bitly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have the bitly gem installed and am setting it up in my ApplicationController to use the API for version 3, but it is throwing the above error. Here is the beginning of my application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  Bitly.use_api_version_3
  before_filter { @cart = find_or_create_cart_from_session }
  before_filter { @bitly = Bitly.new('myusername', 'XXXXXX_API_KEY_XXXXX') }
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you have the Gem installed, but do you have it included in your Gemfile? If the Gem isn't in your Gemfile your application won't find it, which will lead to uninitialized constant errors.